# NSFetchedResultsController + UICollectionView - handling NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to display data from CoreData in a collection view. I tried [AshFurrow's code](https://github.com/AshFurrow/UICollectionView-NSFetchedResultsController/blob/master/AFMasterViewController.m) and other variants to reflect changes in the data observed by `NSFetchedResultsController` to the collection view. It seems to work.

The problem is that I'm doing quite heavy processing of the data in the background which includes adding new items, adding sections, removing sections and even merging sections. This causes significant delays in the UI, scroll. I noticed that most of the time is spent on updating changed collection view items:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{

    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{    

        ....

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
        break;

        ....
    }];
}
```

This code seems to reload items that aren't even visible for no apparent reason. So I changed it to:

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
    if ([[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] containsObject:indexPath])
        [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
    break;
```

This works much faster and the result looks fine.

To the questions:

1. Is this a correct solution? Did I break anything?
2. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Looks fine to me. You could open an issue on https://github.com/AshFurrow/UICollectionView-NSFetchedResultsController/issues and suggest your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit your updates to the relevante index paths by implementing the reloading in
`controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`
rather than in `controllerDidChangeContent:`

Comment: I'm actually caching all the relevant index paths from `controller:didChangeObject` to make a batch update in `controllerDidChangeContent`. `controller:didChangeObject` is called for all changed fetched objects, even invisible.

Comment: Then your solution, while non-standard, is fine.

Comment: @Mundi: The problem is that *UICollectionView* does not have begin/endUpdates methods (as in UITableView). The corresponding UICollectionView method is performBatchUpdates:completion:, but that does not play well with NSFetchedResultsController. AFMasterViewController.m from Ash Furrow is a workaround for that problem, compare http://ashfurrow.com/blog/how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-uicollectionview. As far as I know, there is not "standard" solution.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the link. (Always a pleasure reading your input.) A nice abstracted solution to the problem. In this context, OP's solutions is viable.